Recursion limit when compiling with SBT
I'm in the process of migrating Scala 2.13.14 code to Scala 3.3.3.
A file that used to compile ok in Scala 2, provides this error message with Scala 3:
Recursion limit exceeded.
Maybe there is an illegal cyclic reference?
If that's not the case, you could also try to increase the stacksize using the -Xss JVM option.
For the unprocessed stack trace, compile with -Yno-decode-stacktraces.
A recurring operation is (inner to outer):

  subtype String & K <:< Nothing
  subtype String & K <:< Nothing
  subtype String <:< scala.collection.Map[? >: String & K <: String | K, String]#K
  subtype String | K <:< scala.collection.Map[? >: String & K <: String | K, String]#K
  subtype (String | K, String) <:< (scala.collection.Map[? >: String & K <: String | K, String]#K, String)
  subtype ((scala.collection.Map[? >: String & K <: String | K, String]#K, String)) => (
  K2, V2) <:< ((String | K, String)) => B
        .map { v =>

Maybe it can be solved with some scalacOptions.
It is a very simple source file that contains only:
object EstadoPoolsDB extends Logging {
   ....
}

trait EstadoPoolsDBInfoMBean {
  def getStatus: String
}

class EstadoPoolsDBInfo extends EstadoPoolsDBInfoMBean {

  override def getStatus: String = {
    val status = EstadoPoolsDB.status
    JsonWeb.toJsonString(status, Traducciones.traduccionesPorDefecto, false).toOption.getOrElse(status.toString())
  }
}

Surprisingly, I have many other source files that don't show this problem, even though they are more complicated.
Current scalacOptions:
    scalacOptions := Seq(
        "-deprecation",
        "-explain",
        "-feature",
        "-language:higherKinds",
    )

I'm using Java 21.
The default ThreadStackSize is 1024.
I've obtained this value by running:
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize

I've added -JXss2048 to scalacOptions and the problem persists.
Any hint?

Are you able to come up with a minimal reproducible example that you could share? From the portion you shared, this is surprising.

It's quite time consuming to isolate the error.  What I will try is to comment out different sections of code.

By changing this:
  implicit class ConnectionPoolOps(pool: ConnectionPool){
    def getPoolName(): String = Option(pool).map(_.getName).getOrElse("<null>")
  }

  implicit class ConexionAbiertaOps(conn: ConexionAbierta){
    def poolName(): String = conn.pool.getPoolName()
  }

to:
  extension (pool: ConnectionPool)
    def getPoolName(): String = Option(pool).map(_.getName).getOrElse("<null>")

  extension (con: ConexionAbierta)
    def poolName(): String = con.pool.getPoolName()

it compiles ok.
I think this is a bug in the Scala compiler.
Reported here.

This is unrelated to the original question, but why would you want to replace a type-safe Option[String] with a String that might contain <null>? It just increases entropy by collapsing previously separate states Some[String] and None into one. It's the information-theoretic analogon of pouring kerosene on a bookshelf and setting it ablaze

This code isn't written by me.  I agree, that using Options and not nulls is better
